# What is the difference between 店 and 馆?

Tags: difference

In class I remember my 老师 said there is a difference between 店 and 馆。
For example: 咖啡店 and 咖啡馆。In this context what is the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is difference between 店 and 馆. Actually, it is likely be the convention of Chinese expression.

茶馆: a place where you can drink tea.

茶店: a place where you can buy tea, usually called 茶叶店.

咖啡馆=咖啡店，旅馆=旅店，理发馆=理发店

but 饭馆≠饭店，酒馆≠酒店

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[店](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/99/)(shop; store; commercial establishment) is undoubtedly a business

[馆](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/316/)(1. public building for accommodation 2.public building for cultural activities  3.public building for certain services) may or may not be a business

Answer (score 1):

I think your comment is right, although in my (admittedly) more colloquial Taiwanese-y Chinese, I would probably call it a 咖啡站 instead of a 咖啡館. However, a 店 is probably a store where you buy supplies related to the product.

Answer (score 1):

Supplement to Tang Ho's answer:
Note:
Sometimes you can't tell the meaning of a word from a single character consisting that word. So the following explanation is applied to a character:

店：originally mean warehouse in ancient time, now expand to "place sell goods or service", for example:  inn, shop, fair.

馆: Divided into two parts: left part is "餐", right part is "官". Guess it originally means an official place to provide meals and rest. 
Now it could be:

1. accommodation for guests
2. live, reside (verb. Classical Chinese)
3. hotel
4. house
5. collection e.g. 馆藏
6. restaurant e.g. 馆子

Answer (score 0):

店:
1.商店，卖东西的铺子
杂货～|～铺|～员。

2.旅馆
住～|车马～|旅～。

馆：
1.供宾客、旅客居住的场所
宾～|旅～。

2.一个国家在另一个国家办理外交的人员办公的处所
大使～|领事～。

3.开展文化体育活动的场所
图书～|博物～|体育～|文化～。

4.某些服务行业店铺的名称 
饭～|茶～|理发～|照相～。
The first translation  of 店 sometimes has the same meaning of the last translation  of 馆 and the second translation  of 店 sometimes has the same translation of the first meaning of 馆。

Answer (score -2):

i don't think there is a a difference. Technically, say 咖啡馆 is more oral, 咖啡店 is more literal.

Comment: Could it be one is literally a store you purchase coffee and related products and one is where you sit and enjoy like a cafe?
Like 茶馆 or 茶店?